# How can my program switch from ASCII to Unicode?

Tags: c++, unicode

I want to write a program in C++ that should work on Unix and Windows. This program should be able to use both: the Unicode and non Unicode environments. Its behavior should depend only on the environment settings.

One of the nice features that I want to have, is to manipulate file names read from directories. These can be unicode... or not.

What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: What do you mean by "both the Unicode and non Unicode environments"?

Comment: The easiest way would be to avoid all text processing. What is your program required to do?

Comment: @Nemanja:
I mean that there should be only one program, which behavior should change depending on the environment locale settings, if the settings are Unicode, then the program should behave correctly using the Unicode strings, if the settings are non Unicode (e.g. ISO-8859-1), then the program should work normally, without any changes and need of recompilation.

Comment: @Charles:
one of the nice features that I want to have is to manipulate file names read from directories. These can be unicode... or not.

Comment: Well, you should put that in your question, it's pretty critical information needed to provide a helpful answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I want to write a program in C++ that
>   should work on Unix and Windows.

First, make sure you understand the difference between how Unix supports Unicode and how Windows supports Unicode.

In the pre-Unicode days, both platforms were similar in that each locale had its own preferred character encodings.  Strings were arrays of `char`.  One `char` = one character, except in a few East Asian locales that used double-byte encodings (which were awkward to handle due to being non-self-synchronizing).

But they approached Unicode in two different ways.

Windows NT adopted Unicode in the early days when Unicode was intended to be a fixed-width 16-bit character encoding.  Microsoft wrote an entirely new version of the Windows API using 16-bit characters (`wchar_t`) instead of 8-bit char.  For backwards-compatibility, they kept the old "ANSI" API around and defined a ton of macros so you could call either the "ANSI" or "Unicode" version depending on whether `_UNICODE` was defined.

In the Unix world (specifically, Plan 9 from Bell Labs), developers decided it would be easier to expand Unix's existing East Asian multi-byte character support to handle 3-byte characters, and created the encoding now known as UTF-8.  In recent years, Unix-like systems have been making UTF-8 the default encoding for most locales.

Windows theoretically *could* expand their ANSI support to include UTF-8, but [they still haven't](http://www.siao2.com/2010/07/30/10033760.aspx), because of hard-coded assumptions about the maximum size of a character.  So, on Windows, you're stuck with an OS API that doesn't support UTF-8 and a C++ runtime library that doesn't support UTF-8.

The upshot of this is that:

- **UTF-8 is the easiest encoding to work with on Unix.**
- **UTF-16 is the easiest encoding to work with on Windows.**

This creates just as much complication for cross-platform code as it sounds.  It's easier if you just **pick one Unicode encoding** and stick to it.

### Which encoding should that be?

See [UTF-8 or UTF-16 or UTF-32 or UCS-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473295/utf-8-or-utf-16-or-utf-32-or-ucs-2/)

In summary:

- UTF-8 lets you keep the assumption of 8-bit code units.
- UTF-32 lets you keep the assumption of fixed-width characters.
- [UTF-16 sucks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049947/should-utf-16-be-considered-harmful), but it's still around because of Windows and Java.

#### wchar_t

is the standard C++ "wide character" type.  But it's encoding is not standardized: It's UTF-16 on Windows and UTF-32 on Unix.  Except on those platforms that use *locale-dependent* `wchar_t` encodings as a legacy from East Asian programming.

If you want to use UTF-32, use a `uint32_t` or equivalent typedef to store characters.  Or use `wchar_t` if `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined and `uint32_t`.

The new C++ standard will have `char16_t` and `char32_t`, which will hopefully clear up the confusion on how to represent UTF-16 and UTF-32.

#### TCHAR

is a Windows typedef for `wchar_t` (assumed to be UTF-16) when `_UNICODE` is defined and `char` (assumed to be "ANSI") otherwise.  It was designed to deal with the overloaded Windows API mentioned above.

In [my opinion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234365/is-tchar-still-relevant/3002494#3002494), `TCHAR` sucks.  It combines the disadvantages of having platform-dependent `char` with the disadvantages of platform-dependent `wchar_t`.  Avoid it.

#### The most important consideration

Character encodings are about information interchange.  That's what the "II" stands for in ASCII.  Your program doesn't exist in a vacuum.  You have to read and write files, which are more likely to be encoded in UTF-8 than in UTF-16.

On the other hand, you may be working with libraries that use UTF-16 (or more rarely, UTF-32) characters.  This is especially true on Windows.

My recommendation is to **use the encoding form that minimizes the amount of conversion you have to do.**

> This program should be able to use
>   both: the Unicode and non Unicode
>   environments

It would be much better to have your program work entirely in Unicode internally and only deal with legacy encodings for reading legacy data (or writing it, but *only* if explicitly asked to.)

Comment: UTF-16 is also the internal, native string format of MacOS X and iOS (Cocoa API). Not just Windows and Java. Unix is the odd one out, in fact.

Comment: One important note: The "wide character" Windows API works with UCS-2, not UTF-16.

Comment: There are at least some contexts in which surrogate pairs are supported.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374069%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @Daniel. Windows API works with UTF-16 (including the surrogatees) at least since XP.

Comment: @Daniel: From Michael Kaplan himself: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michkap/archive/2005/05/11/416552.aspx .  Also in MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374069(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You have to decide how you represent the text internally.
This should be constant no matter what else you choose.

Then whenever you read any input you must trans-code from the input format into the internal format. Then from the internal format to the output format on the way out. If you happen to use the same format internal and externally this becomes an identity operation.

UTF-8 is great for storage and transmission as it compresses well.
But I don't like it as an internal representation as it has variable length.

UTF-16: Was supposed to be the savior of all mankind.
But was quickly superceeded by UTF-32

UTF-32: Fixed with. Therefore great for internal representation and manipulation.
Easy to convert to/from UTF-8.
Very bulky (each character takes 4 bytes).

Most OS have either already converted to a UTF string representation or are heading that way. So using an onld obsolte format internally like ISO-8859 just means than calls to the OS will cause extra work as the string is converted to/from UTF. As a result this seems like a waste of time (to me).

Comment: Quick note: UTF16 and UTF32 are subject to endianness issues. UTF8 and UTF16 make it hard to know the number of Unicode Points... but the number of Points being different from the number of graphems, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide which Unicode encoding you want to use e.g UTF-8, ISO-8859-1 etc
Then you should take this into consideration in your C++ in all your string manipulation. E.g. take a look at w_char and wstring.
In a non-Unicode environment I assume you mean that the input variables will be ascii only?

Comment: Yes, only ASCII in non unicode one.

The problem with two versions of the program is that I have to provide both and decide which to run. I'd rather have one program and just run it.

Comment: @Simon: ASCII and UTF-8 are backwards compatible. So all ASCII characters are also UTF-8 characters (no change required). But note ASCII is only 0-127. Oncce you get above 127 then you are talking about ISO-8859-* which define how the codes 128-255 are defined.

Comment: @Simon: What you could do, is use character arrays in your program for the strings. All inputs would be converted to UTF-8 (byte by byte). The ascii chars that are <127 would remain the same, while the rest would be converted according to the schema. What you have to do though is allocate enough space in the array for the UTF-8. A char array is an array of single bytes but in UTF-8 it would be of 2,3 or 4 bytes per character

Answer (score 1):

The locale identifier of "" (empty string) specifies an implementation-specific default locale.  So, if you set the global locale to `std::locale("")` then you will, in theory, get a default locale that is initialized based on the environment's locale settings.  This is about as much help as standard c++ gives you.

This has some major limitations on Windows, where MSVC doesn't proivde any std::locale's with UTF-8 encoding.  And Mac OS X doesn't provide any std::locale other than the culture-neutral "C" locale.

In practice it's common to standardize on UTF-8 encoded std::string everywhere internal to your app.  Then, in those *specific* cases where you need to interact with the OS, do the code conversion as necessary.  For example, you'll use a const char * encoded with UTF-8 to define a file name on unix, but a wchar * encoded with UTF-16 to define a filename on windows.

UTF-8 is a widely recommended internal character set for applications that are intended to be portable. UTF-16 has the same variable-width encoding problems as UTF-8, plus uses more space for a lot of languages.  Also UTF-16 adds a byte-ordering issue and has relatively little support on unix.  UTF-32 is the simplest encoding to work on, but it also uses the most space and has no native support on windows.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would go a different road.

Whatever the format you choose, it should accommodate Unicode, that's a given. However you certainly do not have to feel restricted to using an existing encoding.

A specific encoding is meant to communicate easily, however since Unix defaults to UTF-8 and Windows to UTF-16, it's impossible to have a universal encoding. Therefore I would simply suggest using your own internal representation and apply suitable conversion depending on the OS you are targeting. This being down by a common interface to the functions you need and an implementation per OS/encoding.

Also note that you should be able to change the encoding/decoding on the fly regardless of the platform you are on (eg, you might be requested to use UTF-32 on Unix for a specific file), one other reason NOT to use a given encoding.

To sum it up:

- `ICU` is great
- if you implement it yourself and wish to be somewhat "standard" use UTF-32 (4 bytes per Point)
- if you are tight in memory, 21 bits (< 3 bytes) are sufficient to encode all existing Points

Conversion may seem "computer-intensive" but:

- you can do it stream-wise
- it's much faster than I/O

My 2 cts, as they say :)

Answer (score 0):

The best way I've seen is to have `typedef`s and a very few macros defined based on conditional compilation.  For example:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define mychar wchar_t
#define s(a) L ## a
typedef std::wstring mystringa;
#else
#define mychar char
#define s(a) a
typedef std::string mystringa;
#endif
typedef std::basic_string<mychar> mystringb;
```

and so on.  You would then use strings as `s("foo")` and `mystringa(s("foo"));`.  I've shown two ways to create a string type.  Either should work.

Comment: You've got your `typedef` and `#define` syntax mixed up.

Comment: This is a sensible solution. One thing that I would do in addition is let Windows' macro and type names dominate; i.e. `TCHAR` instead of `mychar`, `_UNICODE` instead of `UNICODE`, and `TEXT` instead of `s`.

Comment: `TCHAR` is very Windows-specific.  Sure, you *could* define it on Unix, but it's not really useful unless (1) you have a library that's overloaded with `char` and `wchar_t` versions of everything, and (2) you actually bother to build both versions.

Comment: @Daniel:  Except that names with leading underscores followed by capital letters belong to the implementation.  That means that _UNICODE and _T() are technically out.  And thanks for the edit; I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @dan04:  The original question was about being able to switch easily between ASCII and Unicode on Windows and Linux.  That implies the libraries are available, or at least that the correct one will be available on the specific Unix being targeted.

Comment: @David: Or it could just be an assumption made by a Windows programmer used to having both "ANSI" and "Unicode" functions without realizing that other platforms don't have that.