# How to convert a std::string to windows-1255 bytes?

Tags: c++, windows-1255

I have a function which receives a hebrew string and send it through a serial port (boost asio) to the device:

```
void T::sendInfoMsg(std::string hebrewInfo)
{
   std::vector<uint8_t> msg{hebrewInfo.begin(), hebrewInfo.end()};
   serialPortProxy.sendData(msg);
}
```

A device doesn't display a text message correctly because it uses windows-1255 encoding. How to convert a std::string to windows-1255 bytes ?

Comment: How is the original string encoded?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle unicode character sequences in C/C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623698/how-to-handle-unicode-character-sequences-in-c-c/3623852#3623852)

Comment: I assume that the original string (hebrewInfo) is UTF-8

Comment: Why assume? Check. If it is, then the conversion is easy to do by hand.

Comment: It will be easiest if you use one of the available character encoding libraries available, for example [iconv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/iconv.3.html) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).