# Unicode and std::string in C++

Tags: c++, string, file, unicode

If I write a random string to file in C++ consisting of some unicode characters, I am told by my text editor that I have not created a valid UTF-8 file.

```
// Code example
const std::string charset = "abcdefgàèíüŷÀ";
file << random_string(charset); // using std::fstream
```

What can I do to solve this? Do I have to do lots of additional manual encoding? The way I understand it, std::string does not care about the encoding, only the bytes, so when I pass it a unicode string and write it to file, surely that file should contain the same bytes and be recognized as a UTF-8 encoded file?

Comment: are you looking at std::wstring?

Comment: Just a wild guess: could it be your `random_string` function is accidentally inserting nulls due to an off-by-one error with the charset string?

Comment: @Charles: That would be just like me :) But I doubt it, as the std::string constructor discards the null from the string literal, and the random_string function just picks a random character from the charset string.

Comment: `std::string` doesn't necessarily discard the null from the string literal.  Usually, it internally represents the string as a null-terminated C-string, in order to easily implement the `std::string::c_str()` function.

Comment: I checked it to be sure, and charset[charset.length() - 1] does not return a null, which means that my function should not be pumping out nulls

Comment: @oystein: I think I know your problem.  It's with the `random_string` function.  See my updated answer.

Comment: `charset[charset.length()]` will be a NUL in a typical implementation of `std::string` (i.e., it actually stores one byte more than it tells you).

Comment: The characters: 'àèíüŷÀ' are not UTF-8. Note UTF-8 is a multibyte character set. This means that charset[x] is not guranteed to get you a whole character as it may be split across more than one char.

Comment: Also note: UTF-8 is a great format for storage and transport. Internally it is a real pain to work with (because it is not fixed width) and you should transform your data into UTF-16 (or UTF-32).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`random_string` is likely to be the culprit; I wonder how it's implemented. If your string is indeed UTF-8-encoded and `random_string` looks like

```
std::string random_string(std::string const &charset)
{
    const int N = 10;
    std::string result(N);
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
        result[i] = charset[rand() % charset.size()];
    return result;
}
```

then it will take random `char`s from `charset`, which in UTF-8 (as other posters have pointed out) are not Unicode code points, but simple bytes. If it selects a random byte from the middle of a UTF-8 multibyte character as the first byte (or puts that after an 7-bit ASCII-compatible character), then your output will not be valid UTF-8. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) and [RFC 3629](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629).

The solution might be to [transform](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/locale/codecvt/) to and from UTF-32 in `random_string`. I believe `wchar_t` and `std::wstring` use UTF-32 on Linux. UTF-16 would also be safe, as long as you stay within the [Basic Multilingual Plane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane).

Comment: So if a std::string named "str" contains "àỳ", str[0] won't return "à"? And str[1] won't return "ỳ"?

Comment: No, it will return the first byte in the multi-byte encoding for these characters. C++ is a 1980s invention, designed to be compatible with C (1970s) and ASCII (1960s), while Unicode and UTF-8 were introduced in the early 90s. UTF-8 was designed to keep *most* old programs and algorithms working, looks like you used one of the algorithms that break. *If* this is more or less what `random_string` does.

Comment: It is. I guess this means that whenever I want to manipulate a unicode string I must use a wstring. I'll read up on portability issues and such. Anyway, answer accepted.

Comment: Correction to my previous comment: `str[1]` will return the second byte in the encoding for `à`.

Comment: Is there anything wrong with using UTF-8 with wstring to solve the problem? Any particular reason why I'd have to convert to UTF-32 (or UTF-16)?

Comment: @oystein: `wstring` on Windows uses UTF-16, so you still have the "half a character" problem, although less often.  It's perfectly reasonable to store Unicode strings in UTF-8 as long as you remember that `char` means "byte", **NOT** "character".

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473295/utf-8-or-utf-16-or-utf-32-or-ucs-2/

Comment: @dan: How does wstring "use" UTF-16?

Comment: Technically, `wstring` itself is encoding-agnostic.  But all of the Windows API and CRT functions that accept `wchar_t`-based strings interpret them as being encoded in UTF-16.  And that MSVC has `sizeof(wchar_t) == 2` so that you *can't* use it for UTF-32.

Comment: Guess I _can_, but I'd get that half character problem again, eh? I'm not writing platform specific code, so hopefully UTF-8 + wstring should not be a problem...

Comment: @oystein, no, you can use UTF-8, it just takes extra processing (and will make your app UTF-8-specific). Since any Unicode codepoint takes at most 4 bytes to encode in UTF-8, you can convert `charset` to an `std::vector<UTF8Char>`, where `UTF8Char` is a `struct` wrapping an `unsigned char [4]` array. (The half-char issue with UTF-16, btw., only occurs when you're handling ancient scripts and the like.)

Answer (score 11):

> What can I do to solve this? Do I have
>   to do lots of additional manual
>   encoding? The way I understand it,
>   std::string does not care about the
>   encoding, only the bytes, so when I
>   pass it a unicode string and write it
>   to file, surely that file should
>   contain the same bytes and be
>   recognized as a UTF-8 encoded file?

You are correct that `std::string` is encoding agnostic.  It simply holds an array of `char` elements.  How these `char` elements are interpreted as text depends on the environment.  If your locale is not set to some form of Unicode (i.e. UTF-8 or UTF-16), then when you output a string it will not be displayed/interpreted as Unicode.

Are you sure your string literal "abcdefgàèíüŷÀ" is *actually* Unicode and not, for example, [Latin-1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1)? (ISO-8859-1 or possible Windows-1252)?  You need to determine what locale your platform is currently configured to use.

**-----------EDIT-----------**

I think I know your problem: some of those Unicode characters in your `charset` string literal, like the accented character "À", are *two-byte* characters (assuming a UTF-8 encoding).  When you address the character-set string using the `[]` operator in your `random_string` function, you are returning *half* of a Unicode character.  Thus the `random-string` function creates an invalid character string.

For example, consider the following code:

```
std::string s = "À";
std::cout << s.length() << std::endl;
```

In an environment where the string literal is interpreted as UTF-8, this program will output `2`.  Therefore, the first character of the string (`s[0]`) is only *half* of a Unicode character, and therefore not valid.  Since your `random_string` function is addressing the string by single bytes using the `[]` operator, you're creating invalid random strings.

So yes, you need to use `std::wstring`, and create your charset string-literal using the `L` prefix.

Comment: This is probably the issue, as I have earlier been able to read a unicode string from a file (encoded in UTF-8) into a std::string and output it to a different file. I'll look into it.

Comment: And this is exactly why I said that you can't store multi-byte encodings in a `std::string`. But for some reason I got downvoted to oblivion.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, because you *can* store multi-byte encodings in a `std::string`.  I just did so in the example above.  You simply can't address a single multi-byte character of the string using the `[]` operator.

Comment: @Charles Yeah the same way I can use a linked list for random access.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be, well I didn't downvote you.  But regardless, your suggestion of using `std::vector<char>` would result in the same problem.  You couldn't address a single complete multibyte character.

Comment: @Charles Yes, but unlike `std::string`, `std::vector` is meant to store raw data.

Answer (score 1):

In your code sample, the `std::string charset` stores *what you write*. That is, if you have used a UTF-8 text editor to write this, what you will receive at output in file would be exactly that UTF-8 text.

UTF-8 is just a coding scheme in which different chars use different byte sizes. However, if you use a UTF-8 editor, it will codify, say 'ñ' with two bytes, *and*, when you write it to file, it will have that two bytes (being again UTF-8 compliant).

The problem may be the editor you used to create the source C++ file. It may use latin1 or some other encoding.

Answer (score 0):

To write UTF-8, you need to use a codecvt facet like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee292123.aspx). An example of how to use it can be seen [here](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=index_cvt.html).

Comment: Those are used to convert wchar_t (UTF-16/UTF-32) into UTF-8. Since the string is already UTF-8 no conversion is required.

Comment: @Martin: There is no guarantee that the string is UTF-8. If the source file was saved using codepage 437, the character `à` will be a single byte with the value 133. (In Unicode, `à` is represent by the code point U+00E0, which UTF-8 encodes as the byte sequence [0xc3, 0xa0].)