# printing string with c++ for language other than english

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2010

Hi I am trying to print a string in c++, which is not in English, and the output is always `????`, for example, I want to print a korean world `'선배'` or Thai word `'ยิ่ง'`, the simple code snippet is as follows-

```
main(){    
string name("선배");// string name("ยิ่ง");
int len=name.size();
cout<<"\n name:  "<<name;
cout<<"\n length "<<len;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
 name:  ??
 length 2
```

Where as if I change the string line by English character as-

```
 string name("ab");
```

OUTPUT:

```
name:  ab
length 2
```

Update: I also tried `wchar_t`, which is also printing question marks.

code-

```
wchar_t *a=L"อดีตรักงานไหม";
wprintf(L"sss : %s \n" , a);
```

I checked the property of the project, **project properties->configuration properties->general** and the Character set is set as ' `Use Unicode Charecter Set`'

Anybody can please tell me what is going wrong? How can I get it printing different languages?

regards

Comment: Do you have an charset for korean includet, like ISO-2022-KR?

Comment: Hi Sempie, sorry but I am not aware of charset, how can I check that?

Comment: @MMH If, as seems to be the case, this is a Windows console (command line) application, then the problem is probably the font for the Command Prompt window. What happens if you open a command prompt and try to display your source code (just using `more main.cpp` or whatever you called it)? Can you read the embedded strings correctly then?

Comment: @AAT you are right when I try to read the main.cpp, I cannot read the string. it shows '???' , how do I change the font of command prompt? and what font should I change?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with korean, but in general you need to do two things:

- Set the correct code page using [std::locale](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale) **OR** use unicode (for example `std::wstring` and `std::wcout`).
- Set your console to a font that can display those characters. The default font in Windows can *not* do this.

If you are using Windows, you can set the console font by using [SetCurrentConsoleFontEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof cfi;
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 16;
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
```

IF you want to set it independent of your actual application or you do not have the prerequisites for the function above, you can have a look at the different guides on the internet, for example [this one](http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt).

I have no clue what font may support asian characters, you will need to check this yourself. Any unicode font should do.

Comment: Korean was just for an example, I tried with Thai alwell having same output

Comment: Due non-romanian charsets generally use double byte lenght, this still could cause issues.

Comment: More info about `string` and `wstring` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/402918/2710064). Also, don't forget to save the code file to UTF8 (or in the correct locale) otherwise the characters will simply 'disappear' from the code.

Comment: @MHH so did you try what I wrote?

Comment: @nvoigt, I used wstring, but having same output. I didn't set the console font though.

Comment: @MHH Then *do* set the console font?

Comment: @nvoigt Can you please update your answer with how do I set the console font and what font should I set?

Comment: [Check my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40337240/3258851) for the first part (using Unicode properly).

Answer (score 0):

You need to write byte order mark (BOM) first then you can print this.

Comment: And how do I do so> can you please give an example?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project in Hebrew using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.

When trying to output string literals of non-English characters in any way, I get either question marks in boxes, or just question marks. I checked to see how the command line handles the situation by saving a file with a Hebrew name in Explorer and then accessing it through CMD. Again, question marks.

I am guessing there is a way to include the language packs in the c++ script (that's what I am looking up now), but saw this and wanted to share what else I found out. By looking at the Disassembly of my code I noticed that the Assembler is mishandling the assignment to the register. When the value (characters) are loaded, the Unicode formatting (right to left) causes the Assembler to flip the parenthesis and shift the first two (last two) values to the opposite side resulting in an unusable value in the register:

```
 eax,dword ptr [ב (0BDF3A0h)]
```

Eeven as I try to save this it comes out wrong: what it should be is a zero, a right-parenthesis, a space, and then the Hebrewcharacter [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzyL1.png)

which should be [(0בBDF3A0h)].

(Somehow in my code, I now have the Unicode for א outputting the value assigned to it...)

I'm looking at how to handle the issue. Hopefully, you know more than I do :-) Good luck!

More:
[As variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHey9.png)
[as string literal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecMPH.png)

Comment: Looks promising: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/creating-a-multilingual-user-interface-application

Comment: Perhaps it makes sense to check if this is true UTF8, UTF-16 or Microsoft's UCS-2 16-bit multi-byte code rendition that is not actually true UTF-8. Hebrew is not my strong point but you can verify character sets online. Also these pointers may help:  https://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/1/9/ucs-vs-utf8/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3473295/utf-8-or-utf-16-or-utf-32-or-ucs-2

Comment: But as a general rule on SO, if you have a question, please post is as a propper question and not an answer in someone else's Q/Q thread.Thanks!