# Equivalent of wstring in C

Tags: c++, c, wchar-t, wstring

How can I read and access Unicode characters with standard C. Previously I was using C++ and `std::wstring` for whole word and 'const wchar_t' for a single characters, which works perfectly( below is example code).

But now I am not allowed to use C++. How can I replace the 'wstring' in C? How can I convert my code to standard C?

```
...
...
const wchar_t small_char[10]={ L'锕',L'吖',L'啊',L'阿',L'呵',L'嗄',L'埃',L'哀',L'哎'};
std::wstring strIn=L"锕吖哎";
std::wstring s_temp=L"";
int length= strIn.length();
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
    if(strIn[i]==small_char[2]){
        s_temp=s_temp+L"ba";
    }
    else if(strIn[i]==small_char[5]){
        s_temp=s_temp+L"pe";
    }
    else{
        s_temp=s_temp+strIn[i];
    }
}
...
...
```

Comment: Take a look at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526430/c-programming-how-to-program-for-unicode).

Comment: To re-iterate the above link: Use utf-8 when possible, and convert up to `wchar_t` when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I replace the 'wstring' in C? How can I convert my code to standard C?

`std::wstring` is just a wrapper for `wchar_t*`.  You can use `wchar_t` directly, you just have to manage the string memory and concatenations manually.

Try this:

```
...
const wchar_t small_char[10] = { L'锕', L'吖', L'啊', L'阿', L'呵', L'嗄', L'埃', L'哀', L'哎'};
wchar_t *strIn = L"锕吖哎";
int length = wcslen(strIn);
wchar_t *s_temp = (wchar_t*) calloc((length*2)+1, sizeof(wchar_t));
int s_temp_len = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (strIn[i] == small_char[2])
    {
        memcpy(&s_temp[s_temp_len], L"ba", 2*sizeof(wchar_t));
        s_temp_len += 2;
        s_temp[s_temp_len] = L'\0';
    }
    else if (strIn[i] == small_char[5])
    {
        memcpy(&s_temp[s_temp_len], L"pe", 2*sizeof(wchar_t));
        s_temp_len += 2;
        s_temp[s_temp_len] = L'\0';
    }
    else
    {
        s_temp[s_temp_len] = strIn[i];
        s_temp_len += 1;
        s_temp[s_temp_len] = L'\0';
    }
}
// use s_temp up to s_temp_len characters as needed...
free(s_temp);
...
```

If you want something more like `std::wstring`, you should pre-allocate a small buffer and resize it whenever you are going to exceed its capacity during concatenations.  A `struct` is useful for keeping track of that:

```
struct my_wstring
{
    wchar_t *data;
    int length;
    int capacity;
};

void wstring_init(struct my_wstring *str)
{
    str->data = NULL;
    str->length = 0;
    str->capacity = 0;
};

void wstring_clear(struct my_wstring *str)
{
    free(str->data);
    str->data = NULL;
    str->length = 0;
    str->capacity = 0;
};

// allocate in multiples of 32
const int delta = 32;

void wstring_append_str_len(struct my_wstring *str, const wchar_t *value, int valueLen)
{
    if ((!str) || (!value) || (valueLen < 1)) return;

    int newLen = str->length + valueLen;
    if ((newLen + 1) > str->capacity)
    {
        // round to next highest multiple of 32
        int newCap = ((newLen + 1) + (delta - 1)) & ~delta;
        wchar_t *newData = (wchar_t*) realloc(str->data, newCap * sizeof(wchar_t));
        if (!newData)
        {
            // memory allocation error, do something!
            return;
        }

        str->data = newData;
        str->capacity = newCap;
    }

    memcpy(&(str->data[str->length]), value, valueLen * sizeof(wchar_t));
    str->length = newLen;
    str->data[newLen] = L'\0';
}

void wstring_append_str(struct wstring *str, const wchar_t *value)
{
    wstring_append_str_len(str, value, wcslen(value));
}

void wstring_append_chr(struct wstring *str, const wchar_t value)
{
    wstring_append_str_len(str, &value, 1);
}

...
const wchar_t small_char[10] = { L'锕', L'吖', L'啊', L'阿', L'呵', L'嗄', L'埃', L'哀', L'哎'};
wchar_t *strIn = L"锕吖哎";
struct my_wstring s_temp;
wstring_init(&s_temp);
int length = wcslen(strIn);
for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (strIn[i] == small_char[2])
    {
        wstring_append_str(&s_temp, L"ba");
    }
    else if (strIn[i] == small_char[5])
    {
        wstring_append_str(&s_temp, L"pe");
    }
    else
    {
        wstring_append_chr(&s_temp, strIn[i]);
    }
}
// use s_temp.data up to s_temp.length characters as needed...
wstring_clear(&s_temp);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent C routines are

```
==                   wcscmp or wcsncmp 
+=                   wcscat or wcscat_s
=                    wcscpy or wcsncpy or wcscpy_s
.size() or length()  wcslen
```

In your case since you are comparing one character at a time, you do not need wcscmp.  Make sure all your strings are null terminated otherwise the non _s versions won't work.