# error when printing special characters in C. The problem is %c vs %s

Tags: c, special-characters

I'm starting with C, I have found a little difference between %c and %s, when must print special characters. I dont know if I'm doing something wrong, or it's a C limitation:

```
unsigned char str1[]="á";

printf("str1 c (%c)\n", str1[0]);
printf("str1 s (%s)\n", &str1[0]);

unsigned char str2[]="áéíóúñ";
printf("str2 s (%s)\n", str2);
```

And the output is:

```
str1 c ( )
str1 s (á)
str2 s (áéíóúñ)
```

In conclusion: when I try write special characters with %c, I cannot see it.

Comment: `á` is not one byte. It's most probably two. [0xC3 0xA1](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00E1)

Comment: With what text encoding? `%c` prints one *char*, which by definition in C is one byte.  Non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 require more than one byte to encode.

Comment: What does `printf("%d\n", strlen(str1))` display?

Comment: Try `printf("str1 x (%X, %X)\n", str1[0], , str1[1]);`

Comment: There's the `wchar_t` with libraries for extended characters. Quite a big topic of it's own. If you are a beginner then don't worry about this for now, just stick to English.

Answer (score 5):

The `%c` format string for `printf` causes the corresponding argument to be converted to and interpreted as an `unsigned char`. An `unsigned char` is 1 byte long. One byte from your non-[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) string does not necessarily correspond to anything you would recognize as a character.

It is likely that your editor, which you used to place some representation of those strings into your source code, encodes the two strings with some [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) encoding scheme. [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/527307/453616) has some information to get you started on dealing with Unicode in C.

The reason things work fine with the `%s` formatting string is that `printf` will just start dumping out bytes until it hits the null byte terminator. Your output terminal is probably set to the same encoding scheme as your editor, so it's able to correctly interpret those bytes the way you intended.

Answer (score -2):

Ok, now I understand it.

If I write:

```
unsigned char str3[]="a";
printf("%d\n", strlen((char *)str3));
```

The output is:

```
1
```

But I write:

```
unsigned char str1[]="á";
printf("%d\n", strlen((char *)str1));
```

The output is:

```
2
```

I understood that the character sizes can be 1, or 2 if are special characters , no?

Comment: This answer is far from complete, and is also quite misleading.

Comment: Please don't post a non-answer as an answer. StackOverflow is not a forum. You might like to take the [tour] or freshen up your memory. ;-) If you have refinement of your question, please edit it.