# Map characters in c from different languages

Tags: arrays, c, string, sorting, mapping

-I'm trying to create a very basic translator in c (greek to english). I have a specific table to match character:
Α=A,  Β=V,  Γ=G,  Δ=D,  Ε=E,  Ζ=Z,  Η=H,  Θ=8, Ι=I,  Κ=K,  Λ=L,  Μ=M,  Ν=N,  Ξ=KS,  Ο=O,  Π=P,  Ρ=R,  Σ=S,  Τ=T,  Υ=Y,  Φ=F,  Χ=X,  Ψ=PS,  Ω=W.

Basically I want to translate iso8859-7 characters to iso8859-1 characters

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <string.h>

char map_table_capital[] = {'a', 'v', 'g', 'd', 'e', 'z', 'h', '8', 'i', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'ks', 'o', 'p', 'r', 's', 't', 'y', 'f', 'x', 'ps', 'w'};

int main() {

  setlocale(LC_ALL, "el_GR.ISO8859-7");
  printf("Enter a string of Greek alphabet characters: ");
  char input[100];
  scanf("%s", input);

  int length = strlen(input);
  int i;

  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (input[i] >= '\u03B1' && input[i] <= '\u03C9') {
      int index = input[i] - '\u03B1';
      input[i] = map_table_capital[index];
    }
  }
  printf("Mapped string: %s\n", input);

  return 0;
}
```

My problem is that whatever input I give ('α') I have the same output ('α') when I should get ('a')

So input: 'αβγ', should have as output: 'avg'. But I get as output: 'αβγ'

Τhe compiler gives me a warning about having 'ks' and 'ps' but I don't know how to fix it, also its giving a warning about "multi-character character constant" about the:

```
if (input_string[i] >= '\u03B1' && input_string[i] <= '\u03C9') {
      int index = input_string[i] - '\u03B1';
```

\u03B1 and \u03C9 which are basically 'α' and 'ω'. I tried basing this code of a simillar one that just reverses the english alphabet:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

  char input[100];
  char map_table[26] = {'z','y','x','w','v','u','t','s','r','q',
                        'p','o','n','m','l','k','j','i','h','g',
                        'f','e','d','c','b','a'};

  int i;
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  fgets(input, sizeof(input), stdin);

  int length = strlen(input);
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'x') {

      int index = input[i] - 'a';
      input[i] = map_table[index];
    }
  }

  printf("Mapped string: %s", input);

  return 0;
}
```

If anyone has any idea I'd really appriciate it, thanks a lot!

EDIT1: I've gone a completly different  route with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LEN 8

int main() {
    char input_letter[MAX_LEN];
    char *mapping_table[] = {"A", "V", "G", "D", "E", "Z", "H", "8", "I", "K", "L", "M", "N", "KS", "O", "P", "R", "S", "T", "Y", "F", "X", "PS", "W"};
    char *greek_alphabet[] = {"Α", "Β", "Γ", "Δ", "Ε", "Ζ", "Η", "Θ", "Ι", "Κ", "Λ", "Μ", "Ν", "Ξ", "Ο", "Π", "Ρ", "Σ", "Τ", "Υ", "Φ", "Χ", "Ψ", "Ω"};

printf("Enter a Greek letter: ");
fgets(input_letter, MAX_LEN, stdin);
int len = strlen(input_letter);


    int num_alphabets = sizeof(greek_alphabet) / sizeof(greek_alphabet[0]);

    printf("%d\n", num_alphabets);
    int index = -1;
    int found = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < num_alphabets; i++) {
        if (strcmp(input_letter, greek_alphabet[i]) == 0 ||
            strlen(input_letter) == len)) {
            printf("%d\n", i);
            index = i;
            found = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found == 1) {
        printf("Mapped to: %s\n", mapping_table[index]);
    } else {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
    }

    return 0;
  }
```

Now my problem is that whatever greek character I give as input the output remains 'A', basically 'i' doesn't increase

Comment: 'ks' and 'ps' are not single characters.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526430/c-programming-how-to-program-for-unicode

Comment: I don't think you want to set your locale to ISO8859-7.  It looks like you're trying to read Greek characters in Unicode, not in 8859-7.

Comment: *If* your input is Unicode UTF-8, one approach might be to use [`mbstowcs`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mbstowcs) on your  `input` array.  That would give you an array of Unicode characters, which you could meaningfully compare to `0x03B1` and `0x03C9`.

Comment: Hmm, `input[i] <= 'x'` is unexpected.  I would expectdc `input[i] <= 'z'`.

Comment: You don't have to merge two different questions into one, you might ask a separate question for your sceond program.

Answer (score 0):

`if (input[i] >= '\u03B1' && input[i] <= '\u03C9')` is false because you compare the char `input[i]` with a universal character name which is larger than a char.  gcc complaints that they are too large to fit a character literal, so you want to enclose those in double quotes instead.  You use `strcmp()` to compare strings.

'ks' and 'ps' are not single characters.  You either need to use a single character encoding or use a bigger type like char16_t or char32_t and possible universal character name in the same encoding as your input.  You probably want your input and mapping table to use the same encoding.

Comment: I think you mean Unicode character and larger than a char.

Comment: @Barmar Yep, fixed.